# JavaScript Objects response mapping

Tags: javascript, json, object, mapping

**REQUEST**:

```
 
[
  {
    "realName": "OnlineOrderDoc-1",
    "preparedBy": "Jack"
  },
  {
    "realName": "GroceryBillDoc-2",
    "preparedBy": "Jill"
  },
  {
    "realName": "makingChargeDoc-2",
    "preparedBy": "John"
  },
  {
    "realName": "GroceryBillDoc-3",
    "preparedBy": "Sam"
  },
  {
    "realName": "makingChargeDoc-3",
    "preparedBy": "Bill"
  }
]
```

**RESPONSE**

```
[
  {
      "OnlineOrderDoc": {
        "preparedBy": "Jack"
      }
  },
  {
      "GroceryBillDoc": {
          "preparedBy": "Jill"
      },
      "makingChargeDoc": {
          "preparedBy": "John"
      }
  },
  {
      "GroceryBillDoc": {
          "preparedBy": "Sam"
      },
      "makingChargeDoc": {
          "preparedBy": "Bill"
      }
  }
]
```

I'm trying to write a function in JS to get the response in the format above. Basically, the function should iterate over response and create Objects within Array Response.
Ex: If Request has **n** Objects with  realName key that ends in `-2`, then the response Object should have **n** Objects within the response Object
NOTE: Request and Response are listed above

I tried using a Map and check if there's an Object within it but it is never falling into else block. I'm open to any other solutions that can get the response

```
const result = (request) => {
const map = new Map();
request.forEach(req => {
const [newName, numberFromName] = req.realName.split('-');
if (map.has(newName)) {
                const current = map.get(name);
                map.set(newName, {current, ...{[newName]: filename}})

            } else {
                map.set(newName, filename)
            }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a `reduce` which iterates over the `request` array.  For each element `curr`, it splits the `newName` and `numberFromName` from the `realname` string. We can use the number to index `acc` and add the `newName` property to the object at that position.

```
const response = request.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const [newName, numberFromName] = curr.realName.split('-');
  acc[numberFromName] = {
    ...acc[numberFromName],
    [newName]: {
      preparedBy: curr.preparedBy
    }
  }
  return acc
}, [])
```